# Toggle NERDTree in seperate window

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

I want to toggle vim in a whole new window and as I searched, I can open vim in new window using:

```
:NERDTree | only
```

So I set this in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle <bar> only<CR>
```

and it works well, however, I cant close it pressing `control n` again. Is there any way to open and close (toggle) nerdtree in a new window only by pressing one keystroke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
nnoremap <C-n> :if getbufvar('%', '&filetype')=='nerdtree' <bar> bd <bar> else <bar> NERDTreeToggle <bar> only <bar> endif<CR>
```

Or the same but in function to make it more readable

```
function! ToggleNERDTree()
  if getbufvar('%', '&filetype')=='nerdtree'
    bd
  else
    NERDTreeToggle
    only
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-n> :call ToggleNERDTree()<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works just as I want

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-)